# How to insert values into Bridge Table in star schema?

Tags: sql-server, insert, business-intelligence, olap, star-schema

I am modelling my database with respect to star schema with bridge tables.
My master Table looks like below. I need to convert this format to star schema.

**MasterTable**

---

*StudentNumber | Subject1 | Subject 2 | Subject 3*

---

1000   |  Biology | Mathematics | Physics
2000   |  Science | Mathematics | NULL 
3000   |  Biology | Mathematics |NULL

---

My db design has 3 more tables now.

1. Fact Table
2. Bridge Table
3. Dimension Table

The structure and Data of these tables are like below

**FactTable - Students**

---

*StudentNumber | SubjectGroupID*

---

1000   |  1
2000   |  2
3000   |  3

---

**BridgeTable - SubjectGroups**

---

SubjectGroupID  | SubjectID

---

1  | 100
1  | 200
1  | 300
2  | 400
2  | 200
2  | 100
3  | 100
3  | 200

---

**Dimension Table - Subjects**

---

*SubjectID  | Subject*

---

100 | Biology
200 | Mathematics
300 | Physics
400 | Science

---

> Inserting values into the Dimension Table

```
insert into Subjects(Subject) (
select distinct Subject1 from MasterTable
UNION
select distinct Subject2 from MasterTable
UNION
select distinct Subject3 from MasterTable)
```

Now, How to insert values into the Bridge table? Do we need to find all combinations of the 'Subjects' and form a group?.

How to do find possible combinations of the dimension table? IS there any other way to insert values into the bridge table?
Please temme how to insert values into the fact table as well in Microsoft SQL Server.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I have edited for better understanding. Hope this looks better and understandable.

Comment: [Please have a read about flagging](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). You've flagged this post twice because you want an answer; this is not what flags are for.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Pardon me. Mistook the meaning of flagging.

Comment: I would control this with a master insert stored procedure that kept track of the IDs involved.  Pass these IDs to other SPs that perform table specific inserts for each table.